# Software updates failing with dependency issues 16.04 LTS

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Recently a software update failed with dependency issues and now they're all failing. The same four modules appear to be the root cause:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 apport
 apport-gtk
 xserver-xorg-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but that reports the same dependency issues. Anyone any ideas?

Here is an edited version of the output:

```
Setting up udev (229-4ubuntu6) ...
addgroup: The group 'input' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
insserv: warning: script 'S98lockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K19gcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K19unlockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'lockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'gcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'unlockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service lockgcstartup if started
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting lockgcstartup depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility '$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting gcstartup depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility '$all' which can not be true!
:
snip: Preceeding pair of lines repeated 47 times --
:
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service speech-dispatcher at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service lockgcstartup at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service lockgcstartup and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package udev (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'S98lockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K19gcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'K19unlockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'lockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'gcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'unlockgcstartup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and urandom if started
insserv:  loop involving service urandom at depth 4
insserv:  loop involving service hwclock at depth 3
insserv: There is a loop between service plymouth and udev if started
insserv:  loop involving service udev at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop at service lockgcstartup if started
insserv: There is a loop at service plymouth if started
insserv: Starting lockgcstartup depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility '$all' which can not be true!
insserv: Starting gcstartup depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility '$all' which can not be true!
:
snip: Preceeding pair of lines again repeated 47 times --
:
insserv: Max recursions depth 99 reached
insserv:  loop involving service speech-dispatcher at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service networking at depth 6
insserv:  loop involving service mountdevsubfs at depth 3
insserv:  loop involving service mountkernfs at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service lockgcstartup at depth 1
insserv: There is a loop between service lockgcstartup and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package apport (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apport-gtk:
 apport-gtk depends on apport (>= 0.41); however:
  Package apport is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package apport-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 apport
 apport-gtk
 xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and tell me if it changes something.

Comment: @Videonauth No, it resulted in the same output I got from apt-get install -f

Comment: @All:  Still not had any luck solving this myself. From other threads it appears that it may be quite a specific problem at the sort of level which I have very little experience! Perhaps a more comprehensive version of the output might help anyone out there diagnose the problem:

Comment: I still cannot apply the regular software updates because of this problem and would really appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve the issue.